# How do I develop ARM templates while using GitHub

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, azure-resource-manager

I'm developing some open source ARM templates using VScode and publishing code to GitHub. I'm wondering how do I effectively develop templates and corresponding parameters file while keeping my local data out of GitHub and having only generic files published. Example is `parameters` file which while needed to be presented in Git with empty values but still required for me locally to be populated with data which is relevant only to my local debugging/deployment scenario.

Comment: gitignore? whats wrong with that?

Comment: If I have gitignore then I can not have parameters file in GitHub either but I want it to be in GitHub but not the same as the one I use for development

Comment: well, create 2 folders? one for reference files one for dev? or name them like dev-lalal.json, prod-lalal.json and ignore accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Rename parameters file to your liking and add it to .ignore file, leave placeholder in it's place.

Comment: that looks like a bit overengineered to me, i tend not to put anything sensitive into those files anyway (or use private repos) :)

Comment: I use VSCode as well and just added: **/azuredeploy.parameters.1.json to my gitignore since that's the default copy/paste behavior of VS Code on param files.  Could change it to * as well, but I've never needed more than one for local testing